# Mixed list of new/updated objects: how to efficiently store them to the DB?

Tags: java, mysql, json, database, web-services

OK, so let's say I have a `list` that contains the following types of objects:

1. Objects that are already stored in the database (have the same PK),
   and are the same as in the database, **not modified**
2. Objects that are already stored in the database (have the same PK), and are **modified** in regards to the stored ones, so they need to be updated
3. Objects that don't yet exist in the database, and are about to be saved

Such list of objects is being sent as a `JSON` to the web-service, and the web-service now has to communicate to the database, and decide what objects to store, update or ignore.

My question is how to do this effectively?

One idea is to iterate the list, and for every object's PK make a query to the database, and check if the object in the database is non-existent, the same, or modified. And then choose the action based on that information.
What bothers me with that approach is a whole lot of queries to the database, just to save some objects. What if only 1 of 100 should really be saved? It is so ineffective.

Is there any better way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can send the whole list  to DB (MYSQL) and do upsert :

```
INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```